# Partial Views in Progressive Web App

Tags: web, view, partial, progressive

We are looking to move to Progressive Web Applications. We are looking at Partial Views for better efficiency. Does PWA have more options for Partial View or do we have to use Ajax?

Answer (score -1):

There is no concept of partials views in PWA. PWA is just a web app packaged as mobile app. That it.

I think you need to checkout the code-splitting of Webpack if you want to load a piece of code on-demand.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Hope that clears your confusion.